# Shifting most significant bit in long problem in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

[JAVA]
I have a small problem, when clearing a bit from a long variable at a specific index.

The method works fine for nearly everything, but fails when i try to clear(set to 0) the msb (most significant bit).

```
public static long clear(long bitSet, int bitIndex) {

    bitSet &= ~(1L << bitIndex);


    return bitSet;
}
```

I really cant wrap my head around this error...

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!

Example: if you put in 524552L it outputs 264L

in binary(same example): 10000000000100001000 --> 100001000

although it should output -- > 00000000000100001000

Comment: "*I really cant wrap my head around this error...*" - What error? Please provide a [MRE], with expected and observed output.

Comment: When i try to clear the msb, it outputs garbage. example: (10000000000100001000 --> 100001000)

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question and provide a full [MRE]. With input, expected and observied output.

Comment: The code is fine, there is no case in which it is wrong, it can clear the msb too. The example only shows that leading zeroes weren't printed, maybe you wanted them? That's just a printing issue.

Comment: Thanks Harold! i was absolutely blind to not see that!
So the bits that are not printed are still zero, but not shown in the sysout?

Comment: @bambi  Yes. When you use methods like `Integer.toBinaryString()` they only return the string starting with the first '1' bit set.  Of course,you can always modify that by padding on the left.

Comment: @WJS thanks for your answer!
Thats good to know! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static final long setBits(final long store, final int startBitIndex, final int bitQuantity, final boolean MSBFormat, final boolean setBit)
{
        if(startBitIndex < 0 || startBitIndex > 63) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("startBitIndex must be at least 0 and cannot larger than 63.");
        if(bitQuantity < 0 || bitQuantity > 64) throw new IllegalArgumentException("bitQuantity must be at least 0 and cannot be larger than 64.");
        //Do not throw IndexOfOutBoundsException for bitQuantity > (64 - startBitIndex). Tolerate. Nothing's gained from that. Its binary after all.
        if(bitQuantity == 0) return store;
        if(MSBFormat && setBit) return ((startBitIndex > 31 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L : ((((store >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | ((0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, 32 - startBitIndex))) << Math.max(0, 32 - startBitIndex - bitQuantity))) << 32)) //left side
            | (startBitIndex + bitQuantity < 33 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFFL : ((store & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | ((0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, Math.min(32, 64 - startBitIndex)))) << Math.max(0, 32 - (bitQuantity - (32 - startBitIndex))))))); //right side
        if(MSBFormat) return ((startBitIndex > 31 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L : ((((store >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) & ~((0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, 32 - startBitIndex))) << Math.max(0, 32 - startBitIndex - bitQuantity))) << 32)) //left side
            | (startBitIndex + bitQuantity < 33 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFFL : ((store & 0xFFFFFFFFL) & ~((0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, Math.min(32, 64 - startBitIndex)))) << Math.max(0, 32 - (bitQuantity - (32 - startBitIndex))))))); //right side
        if(setBit) return ((startBitIndex > 31 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFFL : (store & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | ((0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, 32 - startBitIndex))) << startBitIndex)) //right side
            | (startBitIndex + bitQuantity < 33 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L : ((((store >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) | (0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, Math.min(32, bitQuantity + startBitIndex - 32))))) << 32))); //left side
        return ((startBitIndex > 31 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFFL : (store & 0xFFFFFFFFL) & ~((0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, 32 - startBitIndex))) << startBitIndex)) //right side
            | (startBitIndex + bitQuantity < 33 ? store & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L : ((((store >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL) & ~(0xFFFFFFFFL >> (32 - Math.min(bitQuantity, Math.min(32, bitQuantity + startBitIndex - 32))))) << 32))); //left side
}       
    
public static final long setMSBits(final long store, final int startBitIndex, final int bitQuantity)
{
    return setBits(store, startBitIndex, bitQuantity, true, true);
}

public static final long clearMSBits(final long store, final int startBitIndex, final int bitQuantity)
{
    return setBits(store, startBitIndex, bitQuantity, true, false);
}

public static final long setLSBits(final long store, final int startBitIndex, final int bitQuantity)
{
    return setBits(store, startBitIndex, bitQuantity, false, true);
}

public static final long clearLSBits(final long store, final int startBitIndex, final int bitQuantity)
{
    return setBits(store, startBitIndex, bitQuantity, false, false);
}
```

Comment: That's the most complicated way to do this that I've ever seen, and also note that OPs question was really a confusion about the number of bits being printed, not so much about actually implementing the function `clear`

Comment: OP didnt find the gas pedal of his perfectly fine car. You gave him a space shuttle without any instructions

Comment: Whahhaaahha... It just about zeros padding? Well, never mind about the answer then.